# AWS lambda - "errorMessage": "Apple"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I keep getting this error when I run a lambda function using node 12.x. The function I have has nothing specific to apple- as in push notification etc. Is anyone else facing a similar issue?

Some pointers would be highly appreciated

```
{
  "errorType": "string",
  "errorMessage": "Apple",
  "trace": []
}
```

Comment: If you create a _new_ AWS Lambda function, specifying Node 12.x, then immediately invoke or test the function, does it give this error?

Comment: It does tend to throw this error irrespective.. invoked immediately or after a while

Comment: Who's invoking the function? Can I see the output of console.log(event) inside the function's handler?

Comment: here is the output:using TEST  without any specific parameters but adding the output as requested: ```INFO { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error was the API was returning with `status: 500, statusText:Apple'` and because I were returning a `Promise reject with statusText` it kept sending `Apple` for one of the requests I have resolved this using a try and catch.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created an AWS Lambda function via the management console

  - Runtime: Node.js 12.x
- Clicked **Test**, provided an **Event name**, clicked **Create**
- Clicked **Test**

The function was the default function provided:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

The output was:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}
```

The function ran successfully and did not display the message you received.

Comment: @Radhikavm If you follow the above steps, what happens?

Comment: I do have bunch of other lambda functions that run perfectly fine however it it just this function that tends to throw the error. The function does do a few 3rd party APi calls but they aren't a problem as I tried calling them outside the lamda and they work perfectly fine.

Comment: It almost appears that there is an underlying error that's thrown as above, will try and debug each and every call to check if I can find the exact place its throwing any other error